# How did the visual vocabulary of Super Mario Maker become standardized?

Tags: super-mario-maker, super-mario-maker-2

For instance, a Z shape made with tracks indicates that the player should spin-jump. A track-square seems to be flexible, meaning that *something* should happen in that box (e.g., bouncing off something), but a square open on one side specifically means that the player should throw/kick whatever they're carrying at that spot, in the given direction. Single coins are often used to indicate where a player should try to bounce off enemies; in such levels, two coins stacked may mean the player should bounce twice. These indicators are not generally seen in Nintendo's levels.

(Note: I've never played SMM, SMM2, or a ROM hack. These observations are coming entirely from YouTube videos.)

How/when did the fan community come to develop this "language"?

Comment: Hi Shay!  Unfortunately I don't know if anyone can really give you a definitive answer on this since many parts of this question are subjective or opinions. :( Maybe reduce the scope of the question just to "What other useful visual indicators are there in SMM/SMM2?"

Comment: Most of these visual indicators are legacy from various popular romhacks that have been out for years.  I don't know if there's a glossary of terms but typically you'll get the hang of visual indicators after playing enough of them.

Comment: In game design, there's a word for this type of object placement that makes gameplay more intuitive to the player without explicitly telling them what to do. For the life of me I can't remember the term, but it's common game design, not just in Mario, but many games.

Comment: The problem is that it's too broad: editing in more questions (specific as they may be) makes it even broader.

Comment: I believe most of these conventions probably spread via the twitch (and to a lesser extent youtube) Mario Maker communities. I don't know who the first person who decided to make a Z shaped track for a spinjump was, but people watching a streamer play a level with it in would have picked up on it, seen how useful it was an emulated it. If you fancy going back over three years of VoDs from streamers you could perhaps chart the rise of the conventions!